How to represent that region is disjoint (the exact inverse) from another using GeoSPARQL
TDLR: Can I represent concepts like disjoint directly using GeoSPARQL?
I want to represent (in RDF using my own ontology along with GeoSPARQL) that I have an entity inside some area which is completely disjoint to some other area. E.g. I want to describe when a car exits my suburb (or enters "not my suburb").
I tried to do this by using the geosparql sfDisjoint predicate to represent the location covering the entire earth that is "not my suburb". That didn't work at SPARQL query time because sfDisjoint is rightly treated as a function, not a relationship/property by the query engine.
I'm conscious that I'm not articulate this well. Does anyone understand my problem enough to help me describe it better?
Even better, does anyone understand if I can use GeoSPARQL to actually represent the fact that some location is disjoint rather than merely calculate whether it is as a query result. If not, is there a more appropriate ontology to use to represent such spatial relationships.
Crossposted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79153852/can-i-represent-concepts-like-disjoint-directly-using-geosparql

I do not know about GeoSPARQL, but generally in GIS "disjoints" means the  same than "not intersects"

@user30184 Agree. But my questions is can you use GeoSPARQL to represent that (as opposed to calculate that at query time).

The answer, which came from one of the contributors to GeoSPARQL outside this forum, is that GeoSPARQL ontology geo:sfDisjoint property/relationship is an appropriate way to represent geometric/spatial disjointness.
This is in the GeoSPARQL spec at section 9.2: https://docs.ogc.org/is/22-047r1/22-047r1.html#_dc9619d5-0ced-45ad-92a8-7390c6daea62
The GeoSPARQL query functions are similarly named but exist in a different namespace and are not meant to be used for representation. The geof:sfDisjoint function is covered in section 11.2 of the spec: https://docs.ogc.org/is/22-047r1/22-047r1.html#_b199579b-ac9d-4a2c-9df8-82325eba9660
The original question was raised due to unexpected behaviour within Jena with GeoSPARQL packages inclued. When executing a query where the representation included geo:sfDisjoint the query result would be incorrectly empty. This appears to be a bug/error with the Jena GeoSPARQL packages, not any issue with the GeoSPARQL spec.
